# How do I install UniFi Network Controller and Oracle Java 8 on Raspbian 10 (buster)?

Tags: raspbian-buster, java

I have a LABISTS Raspberry Pi 4 B Model B 4GB with Raspbian 10 installed (Buster). I've been trying to follow [UniFi - How to Install and Update via APT on Debian or Ubuntu](https://help.ui.com/hc/en-us/articles/220066768-UniFi-How-to-Install-and-Update-via-APT-on-Debian-or-Ubuntu) to install the Ubiquiti UniFi Network Controller to monitor my WiFi network, which uses a Ubiquiti access point. Unfortunately this software requires Oracle Java 8.

I've found various articles from a couple of years ago (e.g. [UVC-NVR and JDK 1.8](https://community.ui.com/questions/UVC-NVR-and-JDK-1-8/3a821d41-c788-4c30-898a-5d739315413c#answer/054bee5d-f2ee-4b0e-998d-2f39d0191524)) which rely on `oracle-java8-installer` from `webupd8team`, but unfortunately this installation method is no longer available. I found this SO answer - [E: Package 'oracle-java8-installer' has no installation candidate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55928298/722553) - which describes part of the manual installation process.

How do I complete the process?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working so thought I would share the steps, some of which are similar to the steps in [E: Package 'oracle-java8-installer' has no installation candidate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55928298/722553).

1. Create an Oracle account
2. From the [Oracle download page](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html), download the **Linux ARM v6/v7 Soft Float ABI** 32bit version of Java because it's likely that you have a 64-bit kernel but 32-bit userland. Example: `jdk-8u202-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt.tar.gz`
3. Log in as root: `sudo -i`
4. Extract the tarball: `tar -zxf jdk-8u202-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt.tar.gz -C /usr/lib/jvm`
5. Link the correct name (required by the `/etc/init.d/unifi` startup script): `cd /usr/lib/jvm; ln -s jdk1.8.0_202 jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt`
6. **Optional, not required by UniFi:** Set `JAVA_HOME` for all users: `echo "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt" > /etc/profile.d/java.sh`
7. Install the new versions of Java (JDK *and* JRE, because the JRE is the one that the init.d script looks for):

   ```
    update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/bin/java 100
    update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/jre/bin/java 110
   ```

Now I can run the command I wanted to run in the first place: `service unifi start`

Then I can access the web interface on `http://<IP address of Pi>:8080`.

I hope this answer helps you to install Oracle Java 8 on their Raspberry Pi, especially if you're trying to install it so that you can run UniFi Network Controller!